# React native android modal visible is set to false but still showing

Tags: react-native

I have set modal visibility to false but it still showing. I cant figure out what causes this issue. Maybe somebody had this problem before ?

```
 export default class Controls extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();

    this.state = {
      modalVisible: false,
    }
}

 render() {
   return (
     <Modal
       animationType={'slide'}
       modalVisible={this.state.modalVisible}
       >
     </Modal>
   );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The prop that controls the visibility of the modal is `visible` and not `modalVisible`.

Hence the correct code would be:

```js
export default class Controls extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();

    this.state = {
      modalVisible: false,
    }
}

 render() {
   return (
     <Modal
       animationType={'slide'}
       visible={this.state.modalVisible}
       >
     </Modal>
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It almost works :) when i pass in false with state it doesnt but works fine when i just write in false. Any idea what could be wrong ?